# Locating \smallskip Correctly

Tags: paragraphs, vskip

Does the location of `\smallskip` matter in the following three examples? Version 1 applies `\smallskip` at the end of the previous paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.\smallskip

Keywords: Skip.
\end{document}
```

Version 2 introduces a new paragraph for `\smallskip`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.

\smallskip

Keywords: Skip.
\end{document}
```

Version applies `\smallskip` at the beginning of the subsequent paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.

\smallskip Keywords: Skip.
\end{document}
```

Though the results seem to be similar, I still wonder if their logical meanings are different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always use the second or third forms, which are equivalent, a paragraph after the space makes no difference as  tex is already in vertical mode at that point.

The first adds the space in horizontal mode so it applies after the current line *after the paragraph is broken in to lines*. Try putting it mid-paragraph for example. In practice at the end of the paragraph this will come in the same place as starting it in vertical mode although the code path is quite different.

The main one to avoid is `skip0` in the example below which like your first form has the `\vspace` in horizontal mode, but with white space before it, this can cause an extra spurious line added to the paragraph as the vadjust node prevents the final space from end of line being removed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.
\smallskip

Keywords: Skip0.

This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.\smallskip

Keywords: Skip1.


This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.

\smallskip

Keywords: Skip2.

This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.

\smallskip Keywords: Skip3.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've been using Version 1 because, for example, some skips such as ```\useshortskip``` affects the very next ```\begin{align}```—it seems I need to switch. Thanks for this clarification.

Comment: @JunyongKim `\useshortskip` (from nccmath I assume you mean) does not add a skip in the sense of this question it is a more complicated thing that sets flags altering the behaviour of the following align and explicitly tests to see if it is in vertical mode (cases 2 and 3) or horizontal mode (cases 0 1nd 1) and uses a completely different code path in that case.

Comment: You're right—I was, out of the blue, incorrectly guessing that both ```\smallskip``` and ```\useshortskip``` affect something following.